# Xamarin rendering speed

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new at Xamarin but have some experience on WPF and MVVM.

When building a Xamarin project I create the Views and Bind my ViewModels(Inheriting from INotifyPropertyChanged) to the Views.

But I have noticed that several (more than I wish) samples I have seen on the net create and attach the views elements (ListView etcetera) within the code behind.

My question is. Building the Views from code behind will accelerate the rendering?. Have somebody researched on the speed from one method to the other one?

Comment: there shouldn't be a performance different in XAML vs code-behind.  It is primarily a matter of preference.

Comment: Is it helpful to you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a religious question. Some prefer this, others that.

**XAML** is never required in a Xamarin.Forms program, but it is often more succinct and more visually coherent than equivalent code, and potentially toolable. XAML is well suited for use with the popular MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) application architecture: XAML defines the View that is linked to ViewModel code through XAML-based data bindings.

XAML has several advantages over equivalent code:

- XAML is often more succinct and readable than equivalent code.
- The parent-child hierarchy inherent in XML allows XAML to mimic with
  greater visual clarity the parent-child hierarchy of user-interface
  objects.
- XAML can be easily hand-written by programmers, but also lends itself
  to be toolable and generated by visual design tools.

There are also disadvantages, mostly related to limitations that are intrinsic to markup languages:

- XAML cannot contain code. All event handlers must be defined in a
  code file.
- XAML cannot contain loops for repetitive processing. (However,
  several Xamarin.Forms visual objects—most notably ListView —can
  generate multiple children based on the objects in its ItemsSource
  collection.)
- XAML cannot contain conditional processing (However, a data-binding
  can reference a code-based binding converter that effectively allows
  some conditional processing.)
- XAML generally cannot instantiate    classes that do not define a
  parameterless constructor. (However,    there is sometimes a way
  around this restriction.)
- XAML generally cannot call methods. (Again, this restriction can
  sometimes be overcome.)

and now XAML can be optionally compiled directly into intermediate language (IL) with the [XAML compiler (XAMLC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc).

XAML compilation offers a number of a benefits:

- It performs compile-time checking of XAML, notifying the user of any
  errors.
- It removes some of the load and instantiation time for XAML elements.
- It helps to reduce the file size of the final assembly by no longer
  including .xaml files.